# Algorithm for unique elements in n number of arrays (or objects)

Tags: php, algorithm

Programming Language I am using : PHP

I have 30 results from database, which can be ARRAY or OBJECTs

What I want is an algorithm to find COMMON values.

Ex :

```
$data[0] = array('effected_object_id'=>54,'data'=>array('some_data'));
$data[1] = array('effected_object_id'=>21,'data'=>array('some_data'));
$data[2] = array('effected_object_id'=>63,'data'=>array('some_data'));
$data[3] = array('effected_object_id'=>21,'data'=>array('some_data'));
$data[4] = array('effected_object_id'=>54,'data'=>array('some_data'));
$data[5] = array('effected_object_id'=>21,'data'=>array('some_data'));
...... 30 arrays
```

in above example, in effect_object_id column I have few common elements, like 21(3), 54(2)

I want to get these common elements.

Sorry if this is already asked and solved somewhere, I just googled and tried my head on it. but can't find a FAST SOLUTION, yes I don't need too much of loops here.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I have tried running loops and getting storing repeated values. But it turns out to be very slow method. Basically comparing each array with other arrays.. Lol, I know this makes 30*30 = 900 .

I am sure there must be some faster way around. Like we have array_diff which gives the different objects in the n no of arrays.

Comment: Why is it multidimensional level 3, i mean it could be :
$data[0] = array(21,'some_data') ?

Comment: HamZa DzCyberDeV - Yes it can be. but after then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$groups = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $groups[ $row['effected_object_id'] ][] = $row;
}
```

Comment: awesome code seriously, thanks, i learned a new technique/algo )

Comment: Thank you :) cant select two answers.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to just use an array as a hash table:

Basically, you could create an array formatted as:

```
array[k] = v
```

where k is the effected_object_id and v is an array of entries that have effective_object_id = k.

Like:

```
$vals = array(
    21 => array('data1', 'data2'),
);
```

Like:

```
$indexedData = array();
foreach ($data as $d) {
    $indexedData[$d['effected_object_id']][] = $d['data'];
}
```

And then to find repeated values you could just loop through and check count() > 1.

Depending on your exact needs you may want to structure this approach differently, but hopefully this conveys the basic idea.

It's worth noting that to find the duplicates, this is O(n).  It would actually take <= 2n iterations to find the duplicates.  `n` iterations are required to index the entries, and then another amount of iterations <= n is required to loop through the indexed array and look for the duplicates.

Comment: Thanks Corbin, yes this is the approach.